# "Websocket connection failed" when proxying requests to Next.js app via Apache server

Tags: apache, websocket, next.js

Since upgrading to Next.js 12 I'm getting the following error in the console when I run my Next.js app:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://mysite.local/_next/webpack-hmr' failed

I've discovered that this is related with Next.js 12 using web sockets for HMR connection (unlike previous Next.js versions). In the [guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#nextjs-hmr-connection-now-uses-a-websocket) to upgrading to Next.js 12, the docs provide the following snippet as a fix when using Nginx:

```
location /_next/webpack-hmr {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

However, I use Apache to proxy requests to my Next.js app and can't find an example on how to do this with Apache. I know very little about server configuration or web sockets, so I would appreciate some help in removing that annoying error.

I've searched around and tried a few things on my own, but had no success. Here's one attempt I've made (notice the rewrite rules at the bottom):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName mysite.local
   DocumentRoot "/Users/grazianodev/Projects/mysite"
   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile "/Users/grazianodev/Projects/.crt/mysite.local.pem"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/grazianodev/Projects/.crt/mysite.local-key.pem"    
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
   RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "wss://mysite.local/$1" [P,L]   
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

What i did to make it work:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 # ServerName yourwebsite.local
 ServerName "${WEBSITE_SERVER_NAME}"

 ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

 # Next.js 12 uses websocket
 <Location /_next/webpack-hmr>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr/$1 [P,L]
    ProxyPass ws://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr retry=0 timeout=30
    ProxyPassReverse ws://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr
 </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following for Apache. You might have to tweak the ports and I haven't tested it:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName mysite.local
   DocumentRoot "/Users/grazianodev/Projects/mysite"
   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile "/Users/grazianodev/Projects/.crt/mysite.local.pem"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/grazianodev/Projects/.crt/mysite.local-key.pem"    
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
   
   ## Match webpack-hmr to mysite.local
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPassMatch ^/(_next/webpack-hmr)$  wss://mysite.local/$1
</VirtualHost>
```